# MFC CSocket in a static library

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using the MFC class `CSocket`.  Nothing complicated - open a connection to a server and send a short message.  The code works fine when I link with MFC in a DLL.  However, the call to `CSocket::Create()` crashes when I link to MFC in a static library.

I would like to use MFC in a static library since it simplifies distribution.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193101

The handle maps used by the sockets need to be created for each thread. The following code shows a function to do this:

```
   void SocketThreadInit()
   {
   #ifndef _AFXDLL
   #define _AFX_SOCK_THREAD_STATE AFX_MODULE_THREAD_STATE
   #define _afxSockThreadState AfxGetModuleThreadState()

      _AFX_SOCK_THREAD_STATE* pState = _afxSockThreadState;
      if (pState->m_pmapSocketHandle == NULL)
         pState->m_pmapSocketHandle = new CMapPtrToPtr;
      if (pState->m_pmapDeadSockets == NULL)
         pState->m_pmapDeadSockets = new CMapPtrToPtr;
      if (pState->m_plistSocketNotifications == NULL)
         pState->m_plistSocketNotifications = new CPtrList;

   #endif
   }
```

Comment: Why are you discussing threads?  As far as I remember ( it was 4 years ago! ) the program was single threaded.  Certainly, I do not mention threading in my question.  Anyway, I no longer use MFC - does anyone still?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any linker warnings at all?  Make sure you link the right CRT library depending on your "Code Generation" setting. For Multi-threaded static, you need libcmt.lib for release (libcmtd.lib for debug), also make sure _AFXDLL isn't defined.